# Commands go to sibling SWT control

Tags: eclipse, swt, key-bindings, e4

For Bndtools, I've created a subclass of PackageExplorerPart and added a (staggeringly useful) search Text control.

However, when the Text control is selected/in focus, and I paste, the pasted content goes to the TreeView and creates a snippet project, very annoying.

I debugged the code but can only find that a PASTE Command handler is always going to the TreeView and not to the control in focus. Unfortunately, I cannot find where this is configured. I tried understanding the documentation but could not figure out where to look.

So basically I need to know how to make sure my Text component always is the target of the PASTE handler.

[image: Demo of search field]

Comment: You are aware that `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart` is an internal class and should not be subclassed?

Comment: It looks like the paste handler for that view is `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.refactoring.reorg.PasteAction` there doesn't appear to be a way to change what that does.

Comment: Yes, and I hate to subclass it but this filter function is so important (we have 200-800 project workspaces) that I am willing to follow over time. If there is another way, please tell me.

Comment: Could you point me to some place where it is explained conceptually & concrete how this PasteAction is associated with the PackageExplorerPart? I did notice the key event gets to the proper Text widget but is then forwarded to Display before you can grab it, as far as I can see?

Comment: PackageExplorerPart.makeActions (private) creates PackageExplorerActionGroup which creates CCPActionGroup which creates PasteAction. PasteAction is set to handle the `org.eclipse.ui.edit.paste` command for that view part using IActionBars.setGlobalActionHandler

Comment: Any suggestions how link a search bar to the Package Explorer in a less unhygienic way? And thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Any workbench part in Eclipse gets a chance to register global action handlers via either the `IViewSite` or `IEditorSite` `getActionBars()` method.  If you subclass another part, you would need to make sure that after the super class has registered its handlers you reassign whatever actions you wish with your own handlers.

So in your case, when you want to redirect the 'paste' to your Text control, you could do something like this:

```
IActionBars actionBars = getViewSite().getActionBars();

IAction originalPaste = actionBars.getGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.PASTE.getId());

actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.PASTE.getId(), new Action() {
    @Override
    public void runWithEvent(Event event) {
        Text filterText = filterPart.getFilterControl();
        if (Objects.equals(event.widget, filterText)) {
            filterText.paste();
        } else {
            originalPaste.runWithEvent(event);
        }
    }
});
```